# How to wait thread finish

Tags: multithreading, delphi

hello this is my main thread :

```
 procedure TShareWithForm.btnShareClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Panel1.Visible:= True;

  if SelectedUserID = '' then
  begin
    Exit;
  end;

  TUploadThread.Create(Self);

  Panel1.Visible:= False;

    FormMain.CaseListMyShares;
    Close;
  end;
end;
```

And my execute method in thread:

```
procedure TUploadThread.Execute;
var
  i: Integer;
  CaseId: String;
  tmpFilePath: String;

  curr_cases: Integer;

  obContextIO: TContextIO;

  workingDir: String;
begin

  obShareApiAdapter.IdHTTPWorkBeginEvent:= ShareWithForm.IdHTTP1WorkBegin;
  obShareApiAdapter.IdHTTPWorkEvent:= ShareWithForm.IdHTTP1Work;
  obShareApiAdapter.IdHTTPWorkEndEvent:= ShareWithForm.IdHTTP1WorkEnd;

  curr_cases:= -1;
  SetLength(FForm.SelectedCases, FForm.ShareGrid.RowCount -1);

  for i := 1 to FForm.ShareGrid.RowCount - 1 do
  begin
    CaseId:= FForm.ShareGrid.Cells[0, i];

    if CaseId = '' then
      continue;

    if FormMain.AExists then
        workingDir:= obPath.ServerData + CaseId
    else
        workingDir:= obPath.CaseBackupPath + '\' + CaseId;

    TZipFile.ZipDirectoryContents(obPath.CaseTmpPath + '\' + CaseId + '.zip', workingDir);
    Inc(curr_cases);
    FForm.SelectedCases[curr_cases].patientCase:= CaseId;
    FForm.SelectedCases[curr_cases].rawFile:= obShareApiAdapter.AddNewFile(obPath.CaseTmpPath + '\' + CaseId + '.zip');
  end;
end;
```

When i start to thread, i want to wait thread finish then run this codes :

```
Panel1.Visible:= False;

    FormMain.CaseListMyShares;
    Close;
```

But thread is running parallel.. 
When i show the Panel1 then thread execute, mainthread has to wait thread finish.

How can i wait thread  finish its job?

Panel1 contains a LOADING GIF.

Comment: GUI components can only be accessed from the main thread.

Comment: @LURD let me ask simple, how can i zip huge files in a thread and after zip operation done, say to main thread i am done. When i try to zip in main thread, program crash.

Comment: Add an `OnTerminate` event handler for the thread. There you can handle what happens when thread is finished. If you can't get the code to run in the main thread, debug your code first to fix it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How can i wait thread finish its job?

Use an event driven design. Add an [OnTerminate](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TThread.OnTerminate) event handler for your thread, where you handle what will happen after the thread is finished.

---

***Note:*** There are several flaws in your thread execute handler. All of them are due to direct access of GUI components. That is not allowed.

*Instead, transfer all that information during the thread creation. If you need to update the GUI from the thread, use [Synchronize](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TThread.Synchronize) or [Queue](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Classes.TThread.Queue) methods.*

Answer (score -1):

defeats the purpose of using a thread but you could

```
TUploadThread.Create(Self).WaitFor();
```

Comment: And what if it's created suspended and needs to be started first? And what if it's set to free on terminate? Even if that weren't the case, I wouldn't recommend this even to my worst enemy.